# I can't show images in Flutter at android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

when i build release with --no-tree-shake-icons and open it, everything works but images dont rendering.

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

then i use it

```
  final List<Image> images = [
    Image.asset(
      '../../../assets/manometr.jpeg',
      height: 45.0,
      width: 45.0,
    ),
    Image.asset(
      '../../../assets/molekula.png',
      height: 30.0,
      width: 30.0,
    ),
  ];
```

The pictures are displayed when I launch via Edge, but they are not in the release.

I googled a lot, but all what i got is "change directory" or not correct name of files.
i have no idea what to do.

Comment: Where have you kept images?

Comment: Check the answer that I posted and implement the same.

Comment: ok but i need few minutes to build it

Comment: no, it doesnt work =(

Comment: Image.asset(
      'assets/images/manometr.jpeg',
      height: 45.0,
      width: 45.0,
    )

Comment: it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

**pubsec.yaml:**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Create an **`assets`** folder in the root directory and store images there. Don't make any sub folder.